# Alcohol NMDAR antagonism

Tags: alcohol, pcp

If alcohol is an NMDA receptor antagonist, why doesn't it produce dissociative effects? As far as I am aware, all other drugs that antagonize NMDA receptors function as dissociatives, such as ketamine, PCP, nitrous oxide, DXM, and memantine. Why doesn't alcohol? Is it that its effects on NMDA receptors are too weak? Does it just affect different specific receptors? Or does its effect of GABA somehow counteract NMDA antagonism?